# handling application badge number for my iphone app for apple push notification

Tags: push-notification, badge

I am sending notifications from server side to apns server,i was facing a small problem while handling badge,my badge number should be reduced if user has seen the notification in notification center, if app is already running no need of badge i think so, but always my badge number is "1"

from my server side i am sending badge="1".how to inform to server my app has particular badge number, how to know my badge number.

```
        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
     {
 NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];





    NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in all apps, the unread notification counts are maintained in the server. When the server sends a push notification to a particular device token server sends the badge count along with the payload.

Your server logic needs to keep track of the proper badge count and send it appropriately.

```
{
    "aps" :  
    {
        "alert" : "Your notification message",
        "badge" : badgecount ,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    }
}
```

and instead in your code `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];` 
use

```
badge_value+=[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]intValue];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge_value;
```

where, badge_value is an integer that stores the badge value.

Comment: for that you have to use webservice, in that you have to pass your current badge, and next time server send push with badge+1 in payload.

Comment: how to know my app current badge number

Comment: [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber

Comment: once the user seen the notification in notification center i want to decrement my badge number

Comment: decrement by
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -=1;
and also remove from notification center by 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

Comment: how to remove only my particular notification from notification center, not all notifications

Comment: There is no way to remove a specific notification . The way to remove all the notifications from your app so they don't show in the Notification Center when the user opens the app from one of them.

Comment: @ Viruss mca thank you for u r response valuble information about badging

Comment: if application is in background, i think did receive remote notification will be called 
if application is in suspened(not in back ground), i think did finish launching  will be called or in the suspended state did receive remote notification will be called in that shall i need to check application aa

am i correct?